# create md5 hash of uploaded image

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, md5

I am trying to create a md5 string from the byte array of an image uploaded by users at my web application..
This is because i want the images spread out in different folders.
And I dont have to use the userID as the folder name. Looks more professional.

The result would be something like:

```
/images/ 'first-two-char-of-md5' / 'the-complete-md5-string'.[jpg,png,bmp....]
```

Does this sound as a good solution to handle the images?

So.
My code ( Stuff from the internet.):

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            if (CheckFileType(FileUpload1.FileName))
            {
                const int BUFFER_SIZE = 255;
                Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                Stream theStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                nBytesRead = theStream.Read(Buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ASCIIEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
                //Just trying some stuff to see the output...
                Label1.Text =  ASCIIEncoding.GetString(CalculateMD5(theStream)) + "<br>" + utf8.GetString(CalculateMD5(theStream)) + "<br>" + Convert.ToBase64String(CalculateMD5(theStream));
             }
       }
  }


private static byte[] _emptyBuffer = new byte[0];

    public static byte[] CalculateMD5(Stream stream)
    {
        return CalculateMD5(stream, 64 * 1024);
    }

    public static byte[] CalculateMD5(Stream stream, int bufferSize)
    {
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int readBytes;

        while ((readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            md5Hasher.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, readBytes, buffer, 0);
        }

        md5Hasher.TransformFinalBlock(_emptyBuffer, 0, 0);

        return md5Hasher.Hash;
    }
```

The result. I get some output from the "calculateMD5()" but when i am trying to put it to the label1. to see what is happening. there are just a bunch of wierd characters. 
What am I doing wrong here?  i want it to be htmlsafe... a-z, A-Z,0-9 only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hash is being returned as an array of bytes. You need to convert this to a human readable form, e.g. `73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc`. You can use something like the following:

```
var s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in md5Hasher.Hash)
    s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
return s.ToString();
```

This iterates through the list of bytes returned from the hashing operation and converts each byte to hex. You can find more information on the [format strings you can use for the `byte` type on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y11056e9.aspx).

To answer the first part of your question:

> Does this sound as a good solution to handle the images?

It should be sufficient, although if 2 users upload the same image then it will result in the same hash. You could try salting the data with the username and maybe a timestamp to mitigate this.

You would also need some checking, because even though the probability is extremely small, you may generate the same hash (a 'collision') for different images/users, and you wouldn't want a user to overwrite another user's image. You could prevent this by generating a hash of the image, checking if it already exists, and if it does, add some bytes to the pre-hashed data, repeating until the hash is unique.

Comment: Thanks! about the 2 users with the same image. Do you think that it is possible to add the userID to the _emptybuffer byte[] which in my case is empty (i think), to add the salt??

Comment: Yes, that should work. MD5 uses a checksum to calculate the final hash, `TransformFinalBlock` is a  way to say 'here is the last of the data, and finalize the hashing operation'. Or, you could write any additional data to the end of the stream that you pass to `CalculateMD5` (maybe reading the image data into an intermediate `MemoryStream` first, appending the extra data, and passing the `MemoryStream` to `CalculateMD5`).

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kftcaf9.aspx) class which has a [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) method that can convert an array of bytes to their hexadecimal string representation.

So something like:

```
BitConverter.ToString(CalculateMD5(theStream)).Replace("-","");
```

Will get you your typical hexadecimal string representation of that MD5 hash.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read it because it is an array of bytes and it needs to be converted to a readable string using appropriate encoding.

For example in the [SHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx) class to generate hash:

```
using (System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create())
      return sha.ComputeHash(data);
```

then if you want it into a string to see it into readable form:

```
string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

There are of course [other](http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx) algorithms for generating hash(with or without salt) in addition to SHA256 and MD5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CalculateMD5(theStream).ToString()? Not sure if it would help, but might be worth a try.

Also I would recommend that you save the result from CalculateMD5(theStream) in a local variable, then .ToString() it.

GL, hope something helped.

Comment: No, this would not work. `Console.WriteLine((new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }).ToString());` prints `System.Byte[]` which is not the desired output.