# SQL Server picture database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset

I have a C# application that saves pictures in a SQL Server database. SQL Server keeps pictures in a column of type `varbinary(max)`. And the app converts `byte[]` to show the picture on my screen.

What I want to do is to check the picture whether it was added before. First of all entire database kept by dataset. Then, I tried to compare pictures via checking equality of byte arrays of images. But It does not work. Because (depends on my understanding) the byte array of the picture (which I was intended to add via openfiledialog), does not match the byte array of the picture (which comes from dataset) even they're all same picture (same name, same location, same size etc..)

This brings out more important question on my .Net, C#, SQL Server and ado.net learning.. In such situations, which way is more suitable? To check the data existence on business layer, or on data layer? (sorry my bad english)

Comment: You are correct that different representations of the same image will not be equivalent in direct tests.  You need a consistent representation of the image that you can always compare against.  Tom Studee has suggested such a method (via the previous post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider storing an md5 hash of the image, and use that as the comparison. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802486/214919

Comment: @SertanPekel It depends on requirements of the application, but in general I would advise checking for the existence of business objects in the domain/business layer. Depending on design the check may retrieve the object from some type of cache, or initiate a request to retrieve the object from the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

Many times what we do is save a few additional fields in the table. Like "original file name" which is the name of the uploaded file. The file size, the user, and as mentioned above an md5 hash of the image. This way we can save a lot of work by doing simple compares early in the business logic, and only allow for a full heavy-workload compare at the level you are trying to do.